# Find the centre value of the two highest peaks in a histogram Python

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

I am trying to find the 'middle' value between the highest and second highest peak in a histogram. I can do this manually of course but I want to create an automated method. To calculate my histogram I use:

```
hist= cv2.calcHist([gray_scale_img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
```

so far I have only figured out how to work out the maximum peak value using `max = np.argmax(hist)`. I have attached an image the red is what I am aiming to find.
[HISTOGRAM IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtbmV.jpg)

Comment: Add how you "work out" the maximum peak. The more of your own code you show, the better response you'll get. Otherwise answers will diverge and question gets broad

Comment: Also others might learn purely by reading your question

Comment: using np.argmax(hist) gives me the maximum peak value

Comment: Well ok, put that in your question. **I** know how you get it but maybe not the rest of the world. Put `max_point = np.argmax(hist)`

Comment: Besides that, it's a good question. Upvote

Comment: done, do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Excellent.. I'd love to have a go at it, but it's 2a.m. Gotta hit the bed

Comment: Have a look [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/98365/find-peaks-in-histogram/), [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56701/find-all-peaks-for-mat-in-opencv-c/) and [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/54672/count-number-of-peaks-in-histogram/)... plus have fun on google. BTW, the point you're looking for seems like a locali minima... google that too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can compute the index and value between the top 2 peaks of histogram (using OpenCV and Python 3).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('../test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

#Compute histogram
hist = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

#Convert histogram to simple list
hist = [val[0] for val in hist]

#Generate a list of indices
indices = list(range(0, 256))

#Descending sort-by-key with histogram value as key
s = [(x,y) for y,x in sorted(zip(hist,indices), reverse=True)]

#Index of highest peak in histogram
index_of_highest_peak = s[0][0]

#Index of second highest peak in histogram
index_of_second_highest_peak = s[1][0]


print(index_of_highest_peak)
print(index_of_second_highest_peak)

#If top 2 indices are adjacent to each other, there won't be a midpoint
if abs(index_of_highest_peak - index_of_second_highest_peak) < 2:
    raise Exception('Midpoint does not exist')
else: #Compute mid index
    midpoint = int( (index_of_highest_peak + index_of_second_highest_peak) / 2.0 )



print('Index Between Top 2 Peaks = ', midpoint)
print('Histogram Value At MidPoint = ', hist[midpoint])
```

I have made the assumption that if top 2 peaks are adjacent to  each other, there won't be a midpoint. You may condition this case according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting seems very similar to the [Otsu thresholding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method). In that case you can use

```
ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(gray_scale_img , 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

If your data are strongly trimodal and Otsu's method is not satisfactory, the counterpart would be to apply [kmeans clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) with 3 clusters. Both Otsu's method and kmeans classify data by minimizing the within-class variance. In code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
# Make trimodal data
# (if image is large, consider downsampling it)
n1 = np.random.normal(80, 10, 200)
n2 = np.random.normal(120, 10, 200)
n3 = np.random.normal(180, 10, 400)
imflat = np.r_[n1, n2, n3]
# shuffle and reshape
np.random.shuffle(imflat)
im = imflat.reshape(-1, 1)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(im)
lab = km.labels_
# maxmimum data value in each cluster
[im[np.argwhere(lab==i)].flatten().max() for i in range(3)]
```

This doesn't identify which of the 3 clusters has the highest peak in the histogram though. Apologies for incomplete solution. Another suggestion could be to fit 6th order polynomial to your histogram then find turning points.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I agree that Otsu's method sounds like a good approach for the OP. Consider adding some documentation or maybe a link to a tutorial so that anyone looking up this question in the future can see why/how Otsu's method does what the OP is asking.

Comment: Good intuition, but Otsu won't work in general since it assumes a **bimodal** distribution